# ASIHTTPRequest authentication form behind UIWebview

Tags: ios, uiwebview, asihttprequest

I'm load webView.

```
- (void)loadWebView
    {
            NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:defUrl];    
            self.aRequest = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
            [self.aRequest setValidatesSecureCertificate:NO];
            self.aRequest.shouldPresentAuthenticationDialog = YES;
    
            [self.aRequest setDelegate:self];
            [self.aRequest startAsynchronous];
           
            
            if(!HUD.superview)
                [self.view.window addSubview:HUD];
            [HUD show:YES];

    }
```

[image]

When i try to login (tap to "do so")-  authentication form shows behind my Uiwebview.
[image]

how i can fix this?

Comment: send the webView to the back of the view stack?

Comment: doesnt work, keyboard of Auth dialog not shown